# Insert PostgreSQL function using Psycopg

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

When arguments parameters to the execute method, in the case when using python variables in the form:

```
cur.execute("""
    INSERT INTO some_table (an_int, a_date, a_string)
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s);
    """,
    (10, datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc), "O'Reilly"))
```

All values must be python? Is there an option to pass a PostgreSQL function, for example in the case of UTC time, to pass `NOW()` and not `datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)` or this can only be done in the form:

```
cur.execute("""
        INSERT INTO some_table (an_int, a_date, a_string)
        VALUES (123, NOW(), 'str');
        """)
```

when all values are written in PostgreSQL

Comment: No, you can mix them. If that's your question.

Comment: This is very easy to test. What were your results that you're asking this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ways to do this:

```
cur.execute("""
        INSERT INTO some_table (an_int, a_date, a_string)
        VALUES (%s, NOW(), %s);
        """, [123, 'str'])

cur.execute("""
        INSERT INTO some_table (an_int, a_date, a_string)
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s);
        """, [123, 'now', 'str'])
```

The `'now'` works because this a special case from here [Current Date/time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)